# How to pass multiple arguments to sinter plot --filter_func?

Tags: stim

I'm using [stim](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim) and [sinter](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/81142ac2bf20a9a0a5b2edb6e81860cbe95844c9/glue/sample/README.md) and can't figure out how to pass multiple arguments to `sinter plot --filter_func`. A single argument works as

`--filter_func "metadata['d']<8"`.

I've tried passing multiple arguments a few different ways, e.g.

`--filter_func "metadata['d']<8" "metadata['b']=='x'"`

`--filter_func "metadata['d']<8" --filter_func "metadata['b']=='x'"`

But can't get it to work so I'm wondering how.

My whole process is: first I use the terminal to collect some statistics on different distance surface codes using stim and sinter:

```
mkdir circuits;
python3 -c "
import stim

for p in [0.002]:
    for d in [3, 5, 7, 9]:
      for b in 'xz':
        with open(f'circuits/d={d},p={p},b={b}.stim', 'w') as f:
            c = stim.Circuit.generated(
                rounds=d,
                distance=d,
                after_clifford_depolarization=p,
                after_reset_flip_probability=p,
                before_measure_flip_probability=p,
                before_round_data_depolarization=p,
                code_task=f'surface_code:rotated_memory_{b}')
            print(c, file=f)
";

sinter collect \
    --processes 4  \
    --circuits circuits/*.stim \
    --metadata_func "auto" \
    --decoders pymatching \
    --max_shots 100_000_000 \
    --max_errors 1000 \
    --save_resume_filepath stats.csv
```

And then I plot it using `sinter plot`. I could specify that I only want to plot up to distance 7 even though I collected data up to distance 9 using     `--filter_func "metadata['d']<8"`

```
sinter plot  \
    --in  stats.csv \
    --group_func "f'''p={metadata['p']} b={metadata['b']}'''"\
    --x_func "metadata['d']"  \
    --xaxis "Distance" \
    --filter_func "metadata['d']<8" \
    --show \
    --out plot.png
```

Which gives this plot:
[image]

However I don't know how to specify two filters, like only plotting up to distance 7 and only plotting the b=x line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--filter_func` argument is an arbitrary python expression. In python you combine conditions using `and`. In your case, that means you want this:

```
--filter_func "metadata['d']<8 and metadata['b']=='x'"
```

(All the arguments that end in `_func` are python expression arguments. Internally they are prefixed with `lambda various_args, etc:` , then compiled using python's [`compile` built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile).)

Comment: Perfect thank you!